# Apache: Using reverse proxy and run local website

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

On my linux machine I have apache2 running as a reverse proxy, because I wanted to make another webserver on port 8083 accessible while also making it password protected. For this I added this to my apache2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   <Location / >
       AuthName "Protected Area"
       AuthType Basic
       AuthUserFile /home/pi/.htpasswd
       Require valid-user 
   </Location>
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:8083/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8083/
</VirtualHost>
```

That works like a charm, but now I also want to use apache to serve a site, I would like to do this by making something like /mysite point to /var/www, but I can't really figure out how to do this or if it is even possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is just _naming_ the sites differently an option? That would be the easiest way to have diffent virtual hosts on the same machine...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have two options:

**1.** Put the proxy in a separate `<Location /someurl>` and put the site outside. Requests to `http://localhost/someurl/` will be proxied, everything else is the local site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    <Location /someurl >
        # Password protection omitted for brevity
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8083/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8083/
    </Location>

    # Here is the site
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    # ... etc site config
</VirtualHost>
```

**2.** Use two separate `VirtualHosts`, one for the proxy and one for the site. You will need two separate hostnames pointing to your local ip. For local operations only, use `/etc/hosts`. In this exemple `http://a.localhost/` is the proxy, `http://b.localhost` is the site:

*/etc/hosts:*

```
127.0.0.1       a.localhost
127.0.0.1       b.localhost
```

*Apache config:*

```
# This is the proxy, http://a.localhost/
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName a.localhost
    # Do password protection as needed
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8083/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8083/
</VirtualHost>

# This is the site, http://b.localhost/
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName b.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    # ... etc site config
</VirtualHost>
```

I would probably go for two separate `VirtualHosts`, keeping stuff nicely separated.

Comment: Thanks grebneke, I think that could work (have to try it tonight). I think I will first go for option 1, since I have several devices that need to access it. Maybe I can later buy domain names do that I can easily use option 2.

Comment: @ErikL - I thought you were on localhost. Are you using a domainname already? Just add a subdomain for it?